# Previous screen is popped with current screen either, when user goes back by device or browser back button in drawerContent, react-navigation v5

Tags: react-native, progressive-web-apps, react-navigation-v5, react-native-web, react-navigation-drawer

I'm using `react-navigation-v5` and `react-native-web` in a monorepo architecture.
My stack hierarchy is like this

```
-- drawer
  |-- splashScreen
  |-- authStack
  |-- appStack
        |-- categoryListScreen
        |-- searchScreen
        |-- profileScreen
        |-- aboutUsScreen
```

My first problem was no stack behaviour in **web**. I fixed it by passing a `linking` object to `NavigationContainer` that contains routes, and the heirachy is the exact same as above.

```
const linking = {
    prefixes: [urlPrefixWeb(), urlPrefixNativeDeepLink()],
    config: {
      splash: {
        path: 'splash',
      },
      auth: {
        path: 'auth',
        screens: {
          login: 'login',
          register: 'register',
        },
      },
      app: {
        path: 'app',
        screens: {
          categoryList: 'categoryList',
          search: 'search',
          profile: 'profile',
          aboutUs: 'aboutUs',
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

Now, when I navigate to a random screen inside `appStack` everything works correctly. (ex: from `categoryListScreen` navigating to `searchScreen` or `profileScreen` and then back to the `categoryListScreen` step by step normally as expected); But when I try to navigate to `appStack`'s screens from `drawerContent` component and **going back to the origin screen** by browserBackPress, the **previous screen** is poped either. For example

`categoryScreen` -> `searchScreen` -> `profileScreen` (click from `drawerContent` component). Then backPress **expected bahaviour** is going to `searchScreen` but `searchScreen` is being popped either and goes to `categoryScreen`.

In breaf, `props.navigation.navigate` function that comes from `drawerContent` component doesn't work correctly and does some kind of replacement always.

So does any one know a workaround or related issue to mention?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your stack order is correct. You should insert the routes into the drawer directly.

For example:

```
  |-- splashScreen
  |-- authStack
  |-- appStack
    |-- drawer
        |-- categoryListScreen
        |-- searchScreen
        |-- profileScreen
        |-- aboutUsScreen
```

Comment: So you mean we always need to waste a stack as a parent for drawer?

Comment: No, you can remove appStack,